# UIGestureRecognizer states. Why there's no state like "idle"?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, gesture-recognition

Does anyone have any idea why Apple designed [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) the way that default state is "possible" (*The gesture recognizer has not yet recognized its gesture, but may be evaluating touch events. This is the default state.*) rather then something like "idle"?

The "idle" state in my opinion would make more sense and meaning by eliminating "*but may be evaluating touch events*" part. "Idle" — when UIGestureRecognizer hasn't received any touches and doesn't perform any analysis (touches, timers..). As soon as it receives first touch it changes it's state to "possible", indicating that it performs some sort of analysis (recognition logic).

---

*Context:
I'm writing similar architecture for another platform. So this state would help to separate gesture recognizers which are actually doing something from those which haven't received any touches or just ignored them (for implementing requireGestureRecognizerToFail method).

Comment: Not trying to defend Apples's nomenclature but they do differ between recognizers for _discrete gestures_ and recognizers for _continuous gestures_. _Possible_ actually seems more appropriate name for idle state than _idle_ itself. Hmm, am i making any sense :)

Comment: @rokjarc I don't see connection with discrete and continuos types here. Their "possible" could mean that something happens inside recognizer (e.g. some timers running or some touches being tracked and offsets calculated) _as well as_ nothing happens there at all. I see more sense to have "idle" when nothing happens there at all. The state we get into on reset and till first touch comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We must think in terms of [finite state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). My college automata text: [*Automata and Computability*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Automata_and_computability.html?id=8lKyxS8_CNoC) by Dexter Kozen.

Gesture recognizers are a set of states, including `possible` (`P`), `cancelled` (`C`), and `ended` (`E`). `P` is the start state, `C` and `E` are final states. Between `P` on one end and `C` and `E` on the other, there is a series of states, let's call them the family `S*`. And there are transitions, triggered by touch events and timer events, between all of the various states. The particular arrangement of `P`, the `S*`, `C`, `E`, and the transitions between them all, are what give a particular gesture recognizer its functionality.

For example, let's say we want a single-touch recognizer to call a method if the user performs a single-touch down (`1td`), then single-touch up (`1tu`) within .5 seconds. And otherwise we want it to cancel. So we get the following machine:

```
(P,1td) -> S
(S,1tu) -> E
(S,.5s) -> C
```

Spelled out:

```
When in state `possible`, upon receipt of a single touch-down event, transition to state `S`.
When in state `S`, upon receipt of a single touch-up event, transition to state `ended`.
```

It is when we get to the state `ended` that the gesture recognizer executes our callback. So those two alone would be fine, except that there's a time requirement - the user must release his touch within .5 seconds of the touch-down, or else the gesture is not truly a single touch. So we have a 3rd production:

```
When in state `S`, if a .5 second timer triggers (`.5s`), then enter state `cancelled`.
```

Also, we might have a whole bunch of other things which could happen, such as a 'three touch-down' (`3td`) event. All of these other things would immediately move the machine into the `cancelled` state. So we might have (among many others) this production:

```
(P,3td) -> C
```

And so on.

Thus we can visualize a gesture recognizer as a big machine that takes as input "letters" from an alphabet of input events, accepts (ends) some set of strings in that alphabet, and rejects (cancels) the others. For those of you who don't already know - this is the theoretic underpinning of regular expressions. That's right - gesture recognizers are just parsers of regular expressions over an alphabet of touch and timing events. And the gestures that they recognize are just strings written in that alphabet.

So we get to crux of the question -- why not have an idle state `I` at the beginning, one which 'kicks off' the gesture recognizer into it's `possible` state? The reason is that to transition from `I` to `P` requires an input event. Suddenly, the string that is the gesture being recognized becomes one letter longer -- and thus the gesture recognized is not the gesture we are after, but, for example, a tap and then the gesture, or a touch-down and then a gesture.

*This changes the gesture that is recognized and thus defeats our purpose.*

Comment: Thank you for a detailed SM opus) But how come our gesture become "one letter longer"?.. if this state transition is purely technical question and can be done totally hidden and quite inside the lib (outside of concrete gesture recognizer even). *First* touch begins - touchesBegan method being executed, if no ignoreTouch was called (and thus gesture recognizer began tracking smth) library sets state to possible just after touchesBegan executed. Nothing is broken, but we have an important data available now (idle vs possible).

Comment: Ha! Yes I guess it did go a little long. Let me ask you a question in reply: what is the significant difference between your idle and possible states?

Comment: Having IDLE helps to resolve gesture recognizers relations. Example: implementing "requireGestureRecognizerToFail" functionality. A(pan) requires B(swipe) to fail. But B has delegate with custom shouldReceiveTouch method to ignore all touches except specific area (once side of view). Once A is recognized it suppose to wait for B to fail, but if B is not even tracking any touches (in state IDLE) — no point to wait anything, A can be actually switched to BEGAN state right away. //You might say — just check how many touches B tracks. OK for swipe, but useless for tap:( IDLE is a general solution.